# Mi codigo no entra al while, cuando llega al scanf comienza un ciclo sin fin de captura de números, pero no entra al while

Tags: c, while

Este es el código, el ejercicio es solicitar al usuario cuantos números desea ingresar, luego capturarlos y definir; cuantos son positivos, el promedio de los números positivos y el promedio general de todos los números capturados, para ello definí mis variables;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
//c=cantidad de números a ingresar, numero= el número que ingresa el usuario
//negativo y positivo= almacenaran la suma de los valores

int c, positivo, posicion, i;
float promedioP, promedioT, negativo, numero;

//Les di un valor inicial ya que van a almacenar datos dentro del ciclo,  y posición
//servira como contador 

positivo=0;
negativo=0;
posicion=1;
i=0;

printf("Ingrese la cantidad de números a evaluar: ");
scanf("%d", &c);
    
while(posicion<=c);
{
        printf("Ingrese el numero de la posición: %d",posicion);
        scanf("%f",&numero);
            if (numero>0){
                positivo=positivo+numero;
                i=i+1;
            } else {
                negativo=negativo+numero;
            }
        posicion=posicion+1;
}
    
    promedioP=(positivo/i);
    promedioT=((negativo+positivo)/c);
    printf("Se capturaron %d números positivos",i);
    printf("\nEl promedio de los números positivos capturados es: %f",promedioP);
    printf("\nEl promedio total de todos los números ingresados es: %f",promedioT);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tiene que ser `scanf("%d", &c);`

Comment: Si entra pero antes de lo que tu esperas porque ejecuta una instrucción vacía, al haber puesto un ; antes del cuerpo del while

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que quitarle el **;** al `while`.

El compilador interpreta que debe realizar un bucle donde solo se evalúa la condición `posicion <= c`. Pero un bucle como este no puede hacer nada así que obtienes un bucle infinito.

Solo debes poner **;** luego del `while` cuando antes tiene un `do` (o sea, un ciclo do-while):

```
do {
    ...
} while (...);
```